# What am I doing wrong using the IBM Cloud Block Storage plug-in

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, ibm-cloud, kubernetes-pvc, block-storage

I'm trying to install Jenkins on kubernetes hosted on IBMCloud following this guide:  [Jenkins](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/tutorials/tutorial-for-installing-jenkins-on-IBM-Cloud/). However, I'm not able to do the second step, installing and using the [block-storage plugin](https://cloud.ibm.com/catalog/content/ibmcloud-block-storage-plugin-51baa72d-be9b-487a-8e77-02577d2b5b21-global).

Going through the about-me for the plugin, I'm getting the trouble when I create the PVC and try to apply it. The PVC just remains in a pending state (description below).
I'm in doubt of the process of creating the volume?

```
Namespace:     default
StorageClass:  ibmc-block-bronze
Status:        Pending
Volume:
Labels:        billingType=monthly
Annotations:   volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-class: ibmc-block-bronze
               volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-provisioner: ibm.io/ibmc-block
Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:
Access Modes:
VolumeMode:    Filesystem
Used By:       <none>
Events:
  Type    Reason                Age               From                         Message
  ----    ------                ----              ----                         -------
  Normal  ExternalProvisioning  5s (x2 over 15s)  persistentvolume-controller  waiting for a volume to be created, either by external provisioner "ibm.io/ibmc-block" or manually created by system administrator
```

*Update:*
As I went with another approach of installing jenkins following [Jenkins on K8s](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_r-C_FFDLmU), it restricted what I could try out from the comments.
I was hoping to just use the catalog from IBMCloud, but there seemed to be more to it.

Comment: I have not used this plugin.  But I have recently been through this section to manually create PVCs following the steps here: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/containers?topic=containers-kube_concepts

I happened to be focused on clusters based on Virtual Private Cloud (VPC)

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up the cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud provider? It is important to reproduce your problem.

Comment: what is cluster kube version ? i see the plugin version you are trying to use is v1.7 , thats bit old/deprecated ,you can use the latest version [v2.1.9](https://cloud.ibm.com/kubernetes/helm/iks-charts/ibmcloud-block-storage-plugin) of the block-plugin

Comment: Thank you for taking the time @PowellQuiring
I will look into the docs you have provided.

Comment: Thank you, @MikołajGłodziak.

It is a standard cluster version 1.22.7 created through [https://cloud.ibm.com/kubernetes/catalog/create](IBM Clouds catalog).

Comment: could you paste some logs about this PVC? Maybe you will find information why this process waiting.